# SSRS StripLine Middle date X Axis

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to display a vertical stripline in SSRS2008.

[image]

In this case I would like to display the line the 4th May (Center of the chart)
I don't know how to define the center date of the x axis in an expression.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you want the middle of the `stripline`s to be over the dates then you need to set the `IntervalOffset` property for each `stripline` in the `ChartStripLine` collection. You will need to increase each successive `stripline` by the value of `StripWidth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the centre date with a combination of `DateAdd` and `DateDiff`.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,
 DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Min(Fields!DTE.Value), Max(Fields!DTE.Value))/2,
 First(Fields!DTE.Value)).ToOADate -0.5
```

The `.ToOADate` appears to be necessary to make the StripLine placement work in SSRS 2008 R2. The `-0.5` is to get the StripLine to start between two dates, instead of exactly on the centre date.

In your StripLine properties, add the above expression to the `IntervalOffset` and set the `StripWidth` to 1. Leave the other properties in the Interval category as Auto.

[image: chart with stripline]