# SSRS - Different color on horizontal axis, to show area

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to color area of the horizontal axis, eg. "15.02 05:00" to "15.02 10:00" is red, the rest is black (or just the entire day 15.02, but not 14.02 and 16.02)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Vf0.png)

Nothing, don't know to get the horizontal value

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Although there are expressions to set the the font on the axis, they only seems to affect the whole axis and not individual points on it. However, you could try using a stripline on the main chart area if you just want to highlight a range. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035514/ssrs-stripline-middle-date-x-axis